# Reading 8-bit JPEG in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I have 8-bit colorful JPEG image that Windows Image Viewer can show it correctly. I tried to read it from OpenCV but it failed (returns empty `cv::Mat`). This is the reading code:

```
auto img= cv::imread("c:/1.jpg"); // I tried also with cv::IMREAD_ANYDEPTH
//img.empty() == true
cv::imshow("img", img);
cv::waitKey();
```

---

**JPEG file properties:**

[image]

What did I miss?

**Edit (Build Info):**

```
General configuration for OpenCV 3.1.0 =====================================
  Version control:               1.4.79-1573-gc6780c3-dirty

  Platform:
    Host:                        Windows 10.0.10586 AMD64
    CMake:                       3.4.2
    CMake generator:             Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64
    CMake build tool:            C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/12.0/bin/MSBuild.exe
    MSVC:                        1800

  C/C++:
    Built as dynamic libs?:      NO
    C++ Compiler:                C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe  (ver 18.0.40629.0)
    C++ flags (Release):         /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP8  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C++ flags (Debug):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W4 /GR /EHa  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /wd4251 /wd4324 /wd4275 /wd4589 /MP8  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    C Compiler:                  C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe
    C flags (Release):           /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi    /MP8  /MD /O2 /Ob2 /D NDEBUG  /Zi
    C flags (Debug):             /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi    /MP8  /D_DEBUG /MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1
    Linker flags (Release):      /machine:x64  /INCREMENTAL:NO  /debug
    Linker flags (Debug):        /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL
    Precompiled headers:         YES
    Extra dependencies:          comctl32 gdi32 ole32 setupapi ws2_32 ZLIB::zlib JPEG::jpeg PNG::png vfw32
    3rdparty dependencies:       libwebp libjasper IlmImf libprotobuf ippicv

  OpenCV modules:
    To be built:                 core flann imgproc ml photo reg surface_matching video dnn fuzzy imgcodecs shape videoio highgui objdetect plot superres xobjdetect xphoto bgsegm bioinspired dpm face features2d line_descriptor saliency text calib3d ccalib datasets rgbd stereo structured_light tracking videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc aruco optflow stitching
    Disabled:                    java world contrib_world
    Disabled by dependency:      -
    Unavailable:                 cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev python2 python3 ts viz cvv hdf matlab sfm

  Windows RT support:            NO

  GUI:
    QT:                          NO
    Win32 UI:                    YES
    OpenGL support:              NO
    VTK support:                 NO

  Media I/O:
    ZLib:                        ZLIB::zlib (ver 1.2.8)
    JPEG:                        JPEG::jpeg (ver 90)
    WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
    PNG:                         PNG::png (ver ..)
    TIFF:                        NO
    JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
    OpenEXR:                     build (ver 1.7.1)
    GDAL:                        NO

  Video I/O:
    Video for Windows:           YES
    DC1394 1.x:                  NO
    DC1394 2.x:                  NO
    FFMPEG:                      NO
      codec:                     NO
      format:                    NO
      util:                      NO
      swscale:                   NO
      resample:                  NO
      gentoo-style:              NO
    GStreamer:                   NO
    OpenNI:                      NO
    OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
    OpenNI2:                     NO
    PvAPI:                       NO
    GigEVisionSDK:               NO
    DirectShow:                  YES
    Media Foundation:            NO
    XIMEA:                       NO
    Intel PerC:                  NO

  Parallel framework:            Concurrency

  Other third-party libraries:
    Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
         at:                     D:/hunter/_Base/xxxxxxx/1fbd0c5/1378dcd/Build/OpenCV/Source/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_win
    Use IPP Async:               NO
    Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.4)
    Use Cuda:                    NO
    Use OpenCL:                  NO
    Use custom HAL:              NO

  Python 2:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Python27/python.exe (ver 2.7.13)

  Python 3:
    Interpreter:                 C:/Users/h.helfawi/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe (ver 3.6)

  Python (for build):            C:/Python27/python.exe

  Java:
    ant:                         C:/NVPACK/apache-ant-1.8.2/bin/ant.bat (ver 1.8.2)
    JNI:                         C:/NVPACK/jdk1.8.0_77/include C:/NVPACK/jdk1.8.0_77/include/win32 C:/NVPACK/jdk1.8.0_77/include
    Java wrappers:               NO
    Java tests:                  NO

  Matlab:                        Matlab not found or implicitly disabled

  Tests and samples:
    Tests:                       NO
    Performance tests:           NO
    C/C++ Examples:              NO

  Install path:                  D:/xxxxx

  cvconfig.h is in:              D:/xxxxx
```

**The image:**

This is the image I am trying to open (I could not upload it as image to preserve the meta information) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2CEZBv6I5szWkhnQVFYS29ZdWc

---

Comment: I think you should use imread("c:\\1.jpg")

Comment: slash or double backslash, both do the same in windows file path.. anyway I tried them both

Comment: Have you got an executable called `opencv_version`? If so, try running `opencv_version -v | FINDSTR /I JPEG`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Or just print the output of [`getBuildInformation()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#getbuildinformation), it's all there.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSetchell sorry I could find it and I can rebuild it myself because I am using a pre-built package that I should stick it because of some policies.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, I have edited my question with the build information

Comment: what do you mean by failed

Comment: do you mean it break , or it just return empty mat

Comment: @M.Sabaa It returns empty mat

Comment: is usually a problem with the path

Comment: Try put it on D:\

Comment: Thanks no it is not path problem I can read another 24 depht image in the same path

Comment: Can you possibly upload that image, so that others can try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: This the image: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2CEZBv6I5szWkhnQVFYS29ZdWc   please try to download it as file not saving it as image so the meta data will no be changed

Comment: i tried to read the image in opencv and i got your same problem , i tried then to open it from Photoshop and i got  "Invalid JPEG Marker error" so i think the image is corrupted or so but somehow windows viewer just ignore that and load it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite extension .jpg the file is in GIF format. imread() in the latest version of OpenCV 3.2 can't read GIF format: see [list](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) of supported formats.

Comment: Correct, the file you have supplied is a GIF.